# ActiveMQ Artemis - don't receive all management notifications

Tags: activemq-artemis

I'm trying to connect to the management notifications topic and get all the messages, even before the client was connected.

What is happening is the client only get the notification messages that happened after its connection.

The broker configuration is similar to his

```xml
<management-notification-address>notificationsTopic</management-notification-address>
<addresses>
    <address name="notificationsTopic">
        <anycast>
            <queue name="notificationsQueue" />
        </anycast>
    </address>
</addresses>
```

And the code is [this](https://github.com/apache/activemq-artemis/blob/main/examples/features/standard/management-notifications/src/main/java/org/apache/activemq/artemis/jms/example/ManagementNotificationExample.java).

What I noticed was when the client connects to the notification management topic it creates a new queue and reads from it, but the `notificationsQueue` queue (configured in the `broker.xml`) remains there with all the messages ready to be read.

Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior you're seeing is expected. When a JMS client calls `javax.jms.Session.createConsumer(Destination)` and passes a `javax.jms.Topic` then the broker will automatically create a multicast queue on the address with the same name. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/jms-core-mapping.html) for more details on how JMS maps to core broker resources.

The problem is that the code you're using isn't actually connecting to the `notificationsQueue` which you've configured in `broker.xml`. In order to do that you need to change the client's code to use the [fully qualified queue name](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/address-model.html#fully-qualified-queue-names) (i.e. FQQN), e.g.:

```java
      Connection connection = null;
      InitialContext initialContext = null;
      try {
         // Step 1. Create an initial context to perform the JNDI lookup.
         initialContext = new InitialContext();

         // Step 2. Perform a lookup on the queue
         Queue queue = (Queue) initialContext.lookup("queue/exampleQueue");

         // Step 3. Perform a lookup on the Connection Factory
         ConnectionFactory cf = (ConnectionFactory) initialContext.lookup("ConnectionFactory");

         // Step 4.Create a JMS connection, a session and a producer for the queue
         connection = cf.createConnection();
         Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);

         // Step 5. Perform a lookup on the notifications topic
         Queue notificationsQueue = session.createQueue("notificationsTopic::notificationsQueue");

         // Step 6. Create a JMS message consumer for the notification queue and set its message listener
         // It will display all the properties of the JMS Message
         MessageConsumer notificationConsumer = session.createConsumer(notificationsQueue);
         notificationConsumer.setMessageListener(new MessageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMessage(final Message notif) {
               System.out.println("------------------------");
               System.out.println("Received notification:");
               try {
                  Enumeration propertyNames = notif.getPropertyNames();
                  while (propertyNames.hasMoreElements()) {
                     String propertyName = (String) propertyNames.nextElement();
                     System.out.format("  %s: %s%n", propertyName, notif.getObjectProperty(propertyName));
                  }
               } catch (JMSException e) {
               }
               System.out.println("------------------------");
            }
         });

         // Step 7. Start the Connection to allow the consumers to receive messages
         connection.start();

         // Step 8. Create a JMS Message Consumer on the queue
         MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

         // Step 9. Close the consumer
         consumer.close();

         // Step 10. Try to create a connection with unknown user
         try {
            cf.createConnection("not.a.valid.user", "not.a.valid.password");
         } catch (JMSException e) {
         }

         // sleep a little bit to be sure to receive the notification for the security
         // authentication violation before leaving the example
         Thread.sleep(2000);
      } finally {
         // Step 11. Be sure to close the resources!
         if (initialContext != null) {
            initialContext.close();
         }
         if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
         }
      }
```

Keep in mind that there may be a *a lot* of notifications sent so it's very important that you maintain a consumer on `notificationsQueue` so that messages don't build-up and adversely impact the broker.